# React native video listing like instagram reels and need same performance for loading video

Tags: react-native, video, video-processing, react-native-video, instagram-reels

Currently, I am developing an application similar to Instagram Reel. In that, I used a Mux wrapper.

I am not able to get a performance when loading videos, basically it is taking time to load videos. Is there anything in react native which provides video cache or any other thing by which I can smoothly fetch video without loading delay while scrolling video?

Comment: For that, you need to manage things like playing focused video and pause videos which are outside the view area.

Comment: I have it already, main issue is by doing that it is taking time to load video.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do one thing it just a trick, first you have to set you all data in redux and then you can get data from redux and show in flatlist, hope it will work.

Comment: It is not ideal way, videos are in thousands and in future it will be more then that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).